# Where to place an input .txt file for a jar of your netbeans application

Tags: java

The problem I'm having is rather trivial. I made a simple application in netbeans Java. The application on it's start loads an input file named try.txt for uploading some data. I have placed this file in the project folder and the following code works fine for file read operation

```
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("try.txt");
```

When I debug the program the application works fine. But when I build a jar of my project and run the jar through the command prompt, I get the following error

java.io.FileNotFoundException: try.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

The problem is resolved if I use the absolute path of try.txt like

C:\Desktop\try.txt

But this is not what I want since I'm supposed to distribute the jar to other users as well. I want to know that is there any default directory of my jar where I can put the file. Or Is there any way I can include the file to the jar so it is uploaded upon execution

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should put your text file at the top of your package...i.e.at the root of jar file.

Comment: I'm creating the jar by simply clicking the Clean and Build main Project from the menu bar of the netbeans IDE. should I add it to the Source Packages in my netbeans project ?

Comment: make a folder eg: conf
put your file in it and make it a source folder in your project.

Comment: By folder you mean a java package?

Comment: Byter... Can you please explain the process of adding the source folder a little?. And how to make it a source folder in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the text file in whatever location in the Jar that best suits it.  (The specifics of that come down to which IDE or build tool is being used.)
2. Access the text file by URL obtained as mentioned in the [embedded-resource info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info)..

---

```
URL urltoResource = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.resource");
```

Comment: But how can I put the text file in the jar in the first place?

Comment: *"But how can I put the text file in the jar in the first place?"*  Start with pressing F-1 while your IDE or build tool is on-screen.  Since you don't mention what that build tool is, we'd only be guessing.